# Can custom getters and setters be called simultaneously for the atomic properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, properties, atomic

Are custom getters and setters for the properties declared with the `atomic` attribute will not be called simultaneously or is it just about the internal values that they represent (the ones with underscore characters by default)?

Comment: Declaring a property `atomic` changes how the auto-generated getters and setters are implemented.  If you write custom getters and setters you have to make them atomic yourself.

Comment: @dan Ok. Then you can write an answer and I'll accept it